# Recursively calculate e^x with Java using MacLaurin Series

Tags: java, recursion

I need to write a recursive java method that will compute e^x called e(x,n) with the signature,

```
public static double eThree(double x, long n)
```

and it must use the MacLaurin series to compute e^x, which is the following observation:

```
1 + x(1 + x/2( 1 + x/3(1 + x/4(1 + ... ))))
e(x,0)= 1 A call to this would return a result of 1
```

With some help earlier, I was able to make one that didn't require this format, but I'm not sure what I would code in order to use the format above. Thanks guys, really appreciate any help that will be given!

Comment: The n is the power to which e will be raised.

Comment: I used to know this stuff once upon a time... You should have a go at it yourself first and post your code. If you get it working then great, if not then it gives us something to start with.

Comment: I believe the x is supposed to be the base that is passed, and then n is the power.

Comment: The that is not `e ^ x`. And the formula is specifically for calculating that. Please first be clear with what you want. If you want the value of that formula, then your method should take just single argument.

Comment: @Vimzy Typically, `x` would be the power and `n` would be the number of terms to estimate `e^x` to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you? I believe it implements the algorithm but it does not produce x^n.

```
public static double eThree(double x, long n) {
    return eThree(x, n, 1);
}

private static double eThree(double x, long n, int div) {
    double d = 1;
    if (n > 0) {
        d = d + (x / div) * (eThree(x, n - 1, div + 1));
    }
    return d;
}
```

it seems to think that:

```
2^0 = 1.0
2^1 = 3.0
2^2 = 5.0
2^3 = 6.333333333333333
2^4 = 7.0
2^5 = 7.266666666666667
2^6 = 7.355555555555555
2^7 = 7.3809523809523805
2^8 = 7.387301587301588
2^9 = 7.388712522045855
```

Comment: Yes, this actually did the trick. I like to know what my code is doing. Would you be able to walk me through it?

Comment: @Vimzy - See your equation as `1 + (x/1)*(1 + (x/2)*( 1 + (x/3)*(1 + (x/4)*(1 + ... ))))`. The two-parameter version uses the three-parameter version with a divisor at 1. The three-parameter version then uses recursion decreasing n by one and increasing the divisor by one until n = 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double eThree(double x, long n) {
  return eThreeRec(x, n, 1);
}

public static double eThreeRec(double x, long n, long i){
  if(i==1) return 1;
  else{
    return 1 + (x/i)*eThreeRec(x, n, i+1);
  }
}
```

Can't test it now though.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, `n` here should represent the precision of the McLaurin series (i.e. up to how many terms we calculate). In that case, you should decrement the `n` counter every time you invoke the method recursively. You could write something like:

```
public static double eThree(double x, long n) {
  return eThreeRec(x, n, 1);
}

public static double eThreeRec(double x, long n, long i) {
  if( i >= n ) {
    return 1.0;
  } else {
    return 1.0 + (x/i) * eThreeRec(x, n, i + 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked for some of the tests, but when x is 1.0, and there 6 terms, my tester returns a false, so it isn't working, and I also get a false when x is 1.0 and there are 14 terms.

Comment: Yes, there is a problem with the ``n`` parameter. We should actually be incrementing it instead of decrementing it! This seems to need an auxiliary method, as @OldCurmudgeon's answer states. I'll fix this answer anyway.