# Using electron in a formula in java

Tags: java, algorithm, physics, logarithm

[I'm trying to write a Java program that can take values and put them into a formula involving electron. How can I calculate e^x in Java?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjyY7.jpg)

Comment: See this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/program-to-efficiently-calculate-ex/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate e^x without inbuilt functions in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26140238/calculate-ex-without-inbuilt-functions-in-java) or [Recursively calculate e^x with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22065279/recursively-calculate-ex-with-java-using-maclaurin-series).

Comment: @U880D didn't answer my question

Comment: @Makdous can't be opened

Answer (score 1):

you can use java.lang.Math.exp() method to calculate e^x.
here is an example

```
`
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    double a = 2.0;
    System.out.println(Math.exp(a));
}
//output = 7.38905609893065
`
```

you can read more about this using this link.
https://www.javatpoint.com/java-math-exp-method

Comment: Thanks. Its work 

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Math.exp()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#exp(double)).

**Example:**

```java
import java.lang.Math;

// inside main
Math.exp(1.0);        // e^1
Math.exp(1.6);        // e^1.6
```

Comment: Thnks. It work 

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.lang.Math; 

class Answer { 

    // driver code 
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        double a = 30; 
        double b = 2; 
        System.out.println(Math.pow(a, b)); 

        a = 3; 
        b = 4; 
        System.out.println(Math.pow(a, b)); 

        a = 2; 
        b = 6; 
        System.out.println(Math.pow(a, b)); 
    } 

//you can use Math.pow(e,x);
```

Comment: You did a valid guess but OP was definitely looking for _exponential_ function `Math.exp(double x)` :)

Comment: If someone use Math.pow(a,b) to calculate e^x ,use Math.E as e.But Math.exp() method is more suitable for this.